# Delete all documents using javascript sdk?

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I delete all documents using the JavaScript sdk from the npm package `@elastic/elasticsearch`

This is my best attempt, but it doesn't seem to have any effect:

```
await client.deleteByQuery(() => {
    return { query: { match_all: {} } };
});
```

I have also tried this which causes a `ResponseError`:

```
await client.deleteByQuery({
    index: "*",
    body: "*"
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this instead:

```
await client.deleteByQuery({
  "index": "_all",
  "body": { "query": { "match_all": {} } }
}, (err, result) => {
  ...
});
```

or like this:

```
await client.deleteByQuery({
  "index": "_all",
  "q": "*"
}, (err, result) => {
  ...
});
```